# Does Abkhazia have sandy beaches, or just pebbles like in Georgia?

Tags: beaches, black-sea, abkhazia

A few years ago during a prolonged visit to Georgia I ventured to the most northern beach it was possible to visit, Anaklia, in search of sand.

The beach in Anaklia was pretty dirty and not really ready for tourists yet. I don't remember it being sandy. Batumi and the other beaches I visited were all pebbles rather than sand.

Now that it's a fair bit easier to cross from Georgia to Abkhazia I'm wondering if the beaches up there are also just pebbles or if they are proper sandy beaches.

Comment: I was always surprised people consider Batumi a proper sea resort without them having any sandy beaches.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I think Batumi mainly appeals to Turks, who have beaches but have lots of things they're not allowed to do in their country, to Russians, who don't have beaches where it gets warm, and to Armenians, who only have lakes and no seaside.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pitsunda+beach+photo&tbm=isch&imgil=s-5gr7VGTGYrYM%253A%253BkJa6YB_3P04LTM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.dreamstime.com%25252Feditorial-stock-photo-abkhazia-resort-pitsunda-caucasus-april-sanatorium-complex-ashore-black-sea-city-beach-promenade-climatic-image55978583&source=iu&pf=m&fir=s-5gr7VGTGYrYM%253A%252CkJa6YB_3P04LTM%252C_&usg=__opvagw6V1nRGbu5prPbyTw9OtrA%3D&biw=1772&bih=909&ved=0ahUKEwjtsKm6kfzNAhVLTCYKHbjJAksQyjcINw&ei=vVWMV63eHMuYmQG4k4vYBA#imgrc=_

Comment: @Karlson: Yeah I don't trust the marketing photos but I only did image searches for "Abkhazia", "Batumi", and "Sukhumi" and saw lots of pictures that looked like sand as well as the pebbly ones. All yours do look like pebbles! Abkhazia is big enough to have a good few beaches though.

Comment: @hippietrail From what I remember sandy beaches isn't an option anywhere on that part of the Black Sea coast.  But my memories are from way back when.  The only thing for sure is that Batumi ia not Abkhazia.  You're looking for Pitsunda.

Comment: @Karlson: No it's not but as I mentioned I also went to other beaches all the way up to Anaklia, which is as close as you could get to the Abkhaz border at the time.

Comment: I've now seen the same kind of pebbly beaches further up in Sochi too so sand seems unlikely in Abkhazia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*georgian beaches sand or pebbles?* was asked on [Lonely Planet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-eastern-europe-the-caucasus/georgia/georgian-beaches-sand-or-pebbles) where for Abkhazia:

> •  andrewsmith: The sand in Abkhazia isn't great either. Sokhumi beach is mostly pebbles and only gets snady once you're in the water. Unfrotunately, there are many submerged hazards, remains of recks and old jetties etc as there's no organised government to clear this up. There's a bit more sand at Gagra.

*Do the Black Sea coast of Abkhazia sandy beaches ?* was asked on [quotesis](http://quotesis.com/en/questions/212999) where:

> •  Знаток: There are beautiful sandy beaches on the shores grow pine.

However this recollection (from about 30 years ago) may be 'approximate', or at least not representative of the coast as a whole.

> •  galvanna: there is a sandy beach in Gagra, Gudauta

However galvanna seems to have made a long trip to Anapa (Russia) specially for the sandy beaches there.

> •  miss-olly: Wonderful beaches, sandy little pebble in the main, but clean water and wonderful scenery.

There is a picture under [Beaches in Pitsunda](http://aroundtravels.com/article-about-abkhazia/articles-on-pitsunda/beaches-pitsunda-photo-video-best-sand-beaches-in.html) that appears to show sand rather than pebbles. However [all best tips](http://all-best-tips.com/39513-relax-in-abkhazia-go-to-sandy-beaches.html) mentions for Pitsunda: *sandy beaches and small in size, but cozy* and *there is also a beautiful beach with clean sand, which is located on the pension "Musser"* and *The village also has Lidzava sandy beach. It is surrounded by pine forest. From Pitsunda it is located 3 kilometers. For lovers of quiet places it will fit most.* The same site has for Sukhumi: *pebble beach or mixed gravel and sand*.

Comment: See you on the beach!